# How to calculate the P(the sum of upward face after 7 dice rolls <= 30)

Tags: probability, random-variables, dice

I'm new to probability and am trying to learn the concept of calculating the sum of number after certain number of dice roll.

Could someone please give me a hint as to how to calculate the $$P(\text{the sum of upward face after }7\text{ dice rolls} \le 30)$$

Comment: I'm not sure how to make this not be an ugly calculation. At the end of the day, you wind up having to either enumerate all the rolls that satisfy the criterion (very hard, because there are tens of thousands of them), or else count them indirectly in some manner.

Comment: One way to do the latter is to recursively reduce the number of rolls. If the total sum is to be at most 30, then the sum of the first 6 must be at most 30 minus the last roll; then repeat on the subsequent rolls. Thus $f(m,n)=\sum_{k=1}^6 \frac{1}{6} f(m-1,n-k)$, where the desired quantity is $f(7,30)$, and you have the initial conditions $f(0,0)=1,f(0,k)=0$ for $k \geq 1$. There may be an elegant way to solve this recurrence, though.

Comment: @Ian Thank you so much for taking time and answering my question! Really appreciate it!

Comment: You may try the probability generating function approach. After the expansion, with the aid of computer, you can sum up the coefficients to get the required probability. See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E5%2Bx%5E6%29%5E7 (divide by $6^7$ at the end). If the number of dice is really large, you may just need to use central limit theorem to get an approximate answer.

Comment: @BGM Thanks for helping out! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to powerful tools you can enumerate all possible (and equiprobable) outcomes -- there are $6^7=279\,936$ of them. Then filter by total, there remains $253\,656$ outcomes, The probability is therefore 
$$
\frac{253656}{279936} = 0.906121.
$$
Here is the Mathematica code to do that :

```
x = Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 7];
n = Length[x]
m = Length[Select[x, Total[#] <= 30 &]]
m/n // N
```

If not, the Central limit theorem will give you an approximation as follows. Define a random variable that equiprobably takes the values 1 to 6. Basic computations will tell you that $E(X)=3.5$ and $\sigma_X=1.70783$. The sum ($S$) over 7 trials approximately follows a normal distribution with mean $7\times 3.5$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{7}\times 1.70783$. You then need to compute (using tables or Excel for instance)
$$
P(S\leq 30.5)=0.907891
$$
which is a pretty decent approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to reduce the computation substantially here.
Assume that you have all $6's$ and subtract all cases with sum > 30, using  [stars and bars Th 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics)

Since dice sum pattern is symmetrical,it is the same as cases where sum $\le 18$

You will need to apply inclusion-exclusion on a minor scale to exclude a die face showing $\gt 6$

sum $7: \binom66 =1$
sum $8: \binom76 =7$
$...$
sum $12: \binom{11}6 = 462$
$...$
sum $13: \binom{12}6 - \binom71\binom66 = 917$
$...$
sum $18: \binom{17}6 - \binom71\binom{11}6= 9142$

overall sum = 26,280

$Pr = 1 - 26,280/6^7$